JSON Path - return array element satisfying regex AND string match condition with JsonPath.net
I am using system.text.json.nodes with JsonPath.net.
I have an array of four Json objects:
[
    {
        "Action" : [
            {
                "value" : "Home"
            }
        ],
        "TO Axis" : [
            {
                "value" : "Z Axis:Z.Axis(1)"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            {
                "value" : "Move"
            }
        ],
        "TO Axis" : [
            {
                "value" : "Z Axis:Z.Axis(1)"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            {
                "value" : "Home"
            }
        ],
        "TO Axis" : [
            {
                "value" : "X Axis:MX.Axis(1)"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Action" : [
            {
                "value" : "Move"
            }
        ],
        "TO Axis" : [
            {
                "value" : "X Axis:MX.Axis(1)"
            }
        ]
    }
]

With a single JSON Path query, I want to filter this array by two criteria:

"TO Axis"[0].value regex match with a string, e.g. Z or MX
"Action"[0].value (i.e. is "Home" or "Move")

For example:

Filter values "Z.Axis" and "Home" would return the first element
Filter values "s:Z.A" and "Move" would return the second element
Filter values "MX" and "Home" would return the third element
Filter values "X" and "Move" would return the fourth element
Filter values "Axis(1)" and "Move" would return the second and fourth elements

My problem is that I cannot find a way combine the ?search function in JsonPath.net with other boolean conditions.  I can execute this:
JsonPath jPath = JsonPath.Parse("$[?search(@[\"TO Axis\"][0].value, \"Z.Ax\")]");
PathResult pathResult = jPath.Evaluate(currentStepJson);

But this, for example, isn't recognized by JsonPath.Net:
$[?search(@["TO Axis"][0].value, "Z.Ax") && @["Action"][0].value == "Home"]

How do I combine ?search() with other criteria?

These both work at https://json-everything.net (which is running the latest version of the lib).  Are you getting a parsing error, or is it just not returning anything?

Parsing error.  What additional info about my setup should I provide?

@gregsdennis I am running JsonPath.Net.1.1.0 with a .NET Framework 4.8 application, any CPU, debug mode, VS2022.  I will upgrade to 1.1.4.

You might be encountering the first fix in the 1.1.2 update: "Improved parsing to account for a few missed scenarios involving math operations".  This might have impacted the && as well.
